# Error attempting to install RHEL7 on Dell 7510 laptop

Tags: boot, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux

I created [a boot image of RHEL 7.2](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/68/ver=/rhel---7/7.2/x86_64/product-software) and configured BIOS on my laptop to boot from USB.

The downloaded ISO SHA 256 checksum matches what RH specifies:

```
$ sha256sum rhel-client-7.2-x86_64-dvd.iso 
bb44c18b0f3af401a87246b710a021c94ccaab3e78f90bb04a89c98c5e6dccb6  rhel-client-7.2-x86_64-dvd.iso
```

The USB boot image is recognized by BIOS and grub loads.  I am asked to Install or check hash.

After selecting Install, the following text appears on screen:

```
[0.0000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
[ OK ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[ OK ] Reached target Paths.
[ OK ] Reached target Basic System.
       Mounting Configuration File System...
[ OK ] Mounted Configuration File System.
[7.920070] nouveau E[  PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x614900 0x00800000 (0x1e408200)
```

The system hangs at this point, and is unresponsive.

[image]

What could be causing this to hang/fail?

Comment: No experience with installing RHEL.  'nouveau' hints to the installer attempting to initialize the graphics card.  Have you tried to do some sort of text-based install?  This is possible with various distros.

Comment: It was Switchable Graphics in the BIOS.  I turned that off a couple hours ago and completed the install.  Added answer in case anyone else stumbles across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `Switchable Graphics` was enabled in BIOS.   I unchecked that, and `Enable Dock Display Port`, saved the config and rebooted.  Was able to complete installation normally.

(apologies for the potato img)

[image]